# Validate excel sheet lines against application lines using loop with Ruby

Tags: ruby, capybara

Friends, I'll try to be as detailed as possible. Thomas Walpole It helped me to validate if the information of each row of the worksheet corresponds to each row of the grid of my application. However I would like to use the for to validate this to make it more beautiful. How would I change the solution below?

As I don't know how to use the loop under these conditions, I'll have to do it by hand item by item in my worksheet and validate one by one with the items on the front

My spreadsheet is configured like this:
|                  Element              | Status   |
| Nº Hidrômetro                         |Invisível |
| Leitura                               |Invisível |
| Diâmetro do HD                        |Invisível |
| Filtro                                |Invisível |
| Padrão de instalação do HD            |Invisível |
| Equipamento de telemetria acoplado    |Invisível |

```
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
  book = Spreadsheet.open('c:/temp/gab.xls', "r")
  sheet = book.worksheet 0
  #get the first row referring to the second column
  take_hidrometro_planilha = sheet.rows[1][1]

  pp "O item da planilha N. hidrometro esta configurado para  #{take_hidrometro_planilha}"
  expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(2) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{take_hidrometro_planilha}']")
  #takes the tooltip on the front according to the desired line and saves it in a variable
  take_hidrometro_front = find("tr.tvRow:nth-child(2) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip]")[:tooltip]
  pp "O item do Front N. hidrometro esta configurado para  #{take_hidrometro_front}"
  #validates the worksheet variable with the variable captured on the front
  pp expect(take_hidrometro_front).to eql(take_hidrometro_planilha)
```

#################### HTML CODE ###################################

```
<div style="" class="tvContent">
    <div style="display:table;width:100%; background:inherit;">
        <div style="display:table-cell;">
            <table width="100%" class="tvGrid">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Nome</th>
                        <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Etiqueta</th>
                        <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Tipo Dado</th>
                        <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Valores </th>
                        <th colspan="1" width="1" class="tvHeader">Preenchimento automático</th>
                        <th colspan="1" class="tvHeader">Status </th>
                        <th colspan="1"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr oncontextmenu="if(!this.cancelEvent) {sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',0,'','','');return false;} delete this.cancelEvent;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','Select#',0,'','','');" onmousedown="if(event.ctrlKey) this.cancelEvent=true;" class="tvRow tvRowOdd tvRoll" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">FLAG_INSERIMENTO_LETTURA_E</td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"> Leitura Existente</td>
                        <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap=""></td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"></td>
                        <td align="left" width="1" class="tvCell" valign="center" tooltip=""></td>
                        <td valign="center" align="center" class="tvCell"><img tooltip="Invisível" src="r/std/static/minus16.gif"></td>
                        <td align="center" width="30" style="line-height:1px;padding:0px;" class="tvCell" valign="center">
                            <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',0,'','','','');" class="but">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/menu64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr oncontextmenu="if(!this.cancelEvent) {sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',1,'','','');return false;} delete this.cancelEvent;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','Select#',1,'','','');" onmousedown="if(event.ctrlKey) this.cancelEvent=true;" class="tvRow tvRowEven tvRoll" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">XWFMSLETMATRICOLA_E</td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"> Nº Hidrômetro</td>
                        <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap=""></td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"></td>
                        <td align="left" width="1" class="tvCell" valign="center" tooltip="[AIMPMATRICOLA]">
                            <button onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','AUTOFILLBTN#',1,'','','','');" class="but butAct" tabindex="0" tooltip="Preenchimento automático ativado" type="BUTTON">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/checkboxselected64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="center" align="center" class="tvCell"><img tooltip="Invisível" src="r/std/static/minus16.gif"></td>
                        <td align="center" width="30" style="line-height:1px;padding:0px;" class="tvCell" valign="center">
                            <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',1,'','','','');" class="but">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/menu64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr oncontextmenu="if(!this.cancelEvent) {sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',2,'','','');return false;} delete this.cancelEvent;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','Select#',2,'','','');" onmousedown="if(event.ctrlKey) this.cancelEvent=true;" class="tvRow tvRowOdd tvRoll" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">XWFMSLETLETTURA_E</td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"> Leitura</td>
                        <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap=""></td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"></td>
                        <td align="left" width="1" class="tvCell" valign="center" tooltip=""></td>
                        <td valign="center" align="center" class="tvCell"><img tooltip="Invisível" src="r/std/static/minus16.gif"></td>
                        <td align="center" width="30" style="line-height:1px;padding:0px;" class="tvCell" valign="center">
                            <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',2,'','','','');" class="but">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/menu64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr oncontextmenu="if(!this.cancelEvent) {sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',3,'','','');return false;} delete this.cancelEvent;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','Select#',3,'','','');" onmousedown="if(event.ctrlKey) this.cancelEvent=true;" class="tvRow tvRowEven tvRoll" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">XWFMSLETID_XWFMTDCO_E</td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"> Diâmetro do HD</td>
                        <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap=""></td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"></td>
                        <td align="left" width="1" class="tvCell" valign="center" tooltip="[XGABAIMPID_XWFMTDCO]">
                            <button onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','AUTOFILLBTN#',3,'','','','');" class="but butAct" tabindex="0" tooltip="Preenchimento automático ativado" type="BUTTON">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/checkboxselected64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="center" align="center" class="tvCell"><img tooltip="Invisível" src="r/std/static/minus16.gif"></td>
                        <td align="center" width="30" style="line-height:1px;padding:0px;" class="tvCell" valign="center">
                            <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',3,'','','','');" class="but">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/menu64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr oncontextmenu="if(!this.cancelEvent) {sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',4,'','','');return false;} delete this.cancelEvent;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','Select#',4,'','','');" onmousedown="if(event.ctrlKey) this.cancelEvent=true;" class="tvRow tvRowOdd tvRoll" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">XWFMSLETSIGILLO_E</td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"> Filtro</td>
                        <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap=""></td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"></td>
                        <td align="left" width="1" class="tvCell" valign="center" tooltip="[XWFMAIMPSIGILLO]">
                            <button onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','AUTOFILLBTN#',4,'','','','');" class="but butAct" tabindex="0" tooltip="Preenchimento automático ativado" type="BUTTON">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/checkboxselected64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="center" align="center" class="tvCell"><img tooltip="Invisível" src="r/std/static/minus16.gif"></td>
                        <td align="center" width="30" style="line-height:1px;padding:0px;" class="tvCell" valign="center">
                            <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',4,'','','','');" class="but">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/menu64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr oncontextmenu="if(!this.cancelEvent) {sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',5,'','','');return false;} delete this.cancelEvent;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','Select#',5,'','','');" onmousedown="if(event.ctrlKey) this.cancelEvent=true;" class="tvRow tvRowEven tvRoll" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">XWFMSLETID_XWFMTUBI_E</td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"> Padrão de instalação do HD</td>
                        <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap=""></td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"></td>
                        <td align="left" width="1" class="tvCell" valign="center" tooltip="[XWFMAIMPID_XWFMTUBI]">
                            <button onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','AUTOFILLBTN#',5,'','','','');" class="but butAct" tabindex="0" tooltip="Preenchimento automático ativado" type="BUTTON">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/checkboxselected64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="center" align="center" class="tvCell"><img tooltip="Invisível" src="r/std/static/minus16.gif"></td>
                        <td align="center" width="30" style="line-height:1px;padding:0px;" class="tvCell" valign="center">
                            <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',5,'','','','');" class="but">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/menu64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr oncontextmenu="if(!this.cancelEvent) {sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',6,'','','');return false;} delete this.cancelEvent;" onclick="if(notSelecting()) sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'TVXWFMTGINSTATOCE','1d13','Select#',6,'','','');" onmousedown="if(event.ctrlKey) this.cancelEvent=true;" class="tvRow tvRowOdd tvRoll" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell">XGABSLETTELCOUPEQUIP_E</td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"> Equipamento de telemetria acoplado</td>
                        <td align="left" class="tvCell" valign="center" nowrap=""></td>
                        <td valign="center" align="left" class="tvCell"></td>
                        <td align="left" width="1" class="tvCell" valign="center" tooltip="[XGABAIMPTELCOUPEQUIP]">
                            <button onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','AUTOFILLBTN#',6,'','','','');" class="but butAct" tabindex="0" tooltip="Preenchimento automático ativado" type="BUTTON">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/checkboxselected64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="center" align="center" class="tvCell"><img tooltip="Invisível" src="r/std/static/minus16.gif"></td>
                        <td align="center" width="30" style="line-height:1px;padding:0px;" class="tvCell" valign="center">
                            <div onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;sendEvent(0,event,this,searchImage(this),0,'','1d13','BtnDropDownRow#',6,'','','','');" class="but">
                                <div><img src="r/std/icons/menu64.png" class="icon" draggable="false" align="absmiddle"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: what library are you using to read the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the 'spreadsheet' gem - the guide provides all the info you need to see how to use a loop here - https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md

```
sheet.each 1 do |row|
  expected_tooltip = row[1]
  expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{expected_tooltip}']")
end
```

That is all you need to do to verify all the tooltip texts in your spreadsheet exist on the page.

If you need to verify they are in a specific order (why?) then you'd probably need something like

```
xls_offset = 1
row_offset = 2
sheet.each_with_index(xls_offset) do |row, idx|
  expected_tooltip = row[1]
  expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(#{row_offset+idx}) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{expected_tooltip}']")
end
```

Comment: It's not like this. I need to read the excel sheet and validate that the status column text matches each screen tooltip text.

Comment: @Elis That is exactly what the code I posted does. Learn about CSS attribute selectors and you’ll see that none of the extra stuff you’re trying to do is necessary

Comment: I've tried several times it always gives an error on the next line, I don't understand. I left my spreadsheet with only one record on the line and it says the error is on the next line.   Reason:, expected `#<Capybara::Session>.has_css?("tr.tvRow:nth-child(1) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='Invisível']")` to be truthy, got false,   
If the worksheet has 59 lines, which is my case, it gives an error on line 60.

Comment: @Elis What do you mean by "on the next line". From that error it looks like you haven't actually installed the Capybara RSpec matchers -- did you follow the instructions from the Capybara README for using with RSpec - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/README.md#using-capybara-with-rspec ?  If you have installed them the error would be something like `expected to have css ...` with a lot more details on why it's failing.  It would not refer to `has_css?`

Comment: Where in the error message does it show that the error is on line 60?  Please provide the full error output so there's enough information to have some idea of what you're doing. It sounds like your spreadsheet may be longer than what's shown on the page?

Comment: i have capybara installed with rspec, this is part of my automated test. The problem is that it is not relating the row of the worksheet with the item on the screen.                                    Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
  book = Spreadsheet.open('c:/temp/gabi.xls', "r")
  sheet = book.worksheet 0     xls_offset = 1
  row_offset = 1
  sheet.each_with_index(xls_offset) do |row, idx|
  pp expected_tooltip = row[1]
   expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(#{row_offset+idx}) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{expected_tooltip}']")
end

Comment: @Elis As I stated, You don't have Capybaras RSpec matchers installed correctly in your environment, because if you did you would be getting a different error message.  Update your question with exactly what you are running, and the FULL EXACT error message you're getting.  Also, please explain how you know the issue is happening in line 60?  In this question you stated all you needed help with was the spreadsheet loop, but it seems like the rest of your code wasn't working either?  You REALLY need to explain what you're doing, what is working and what isn't working.

Comment: I have 58 rows in my worksheet with status = Invisible, on my front I have 58 elements with tooltips = Invisible. It looks like the loop is not correlating correctly.                 Reason:, expected `#<Capybara::Session>.has_css?("tr.tvRow:nth-child(60) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='']")` to be truthy, got false,     expected `#<Capybara::Session>.has_css?("tr.tvRow:nth-child(60) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='']")` to be truthy, got false (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)

Comment: xls_offset = 1
  row_offset = 2
  sheet.each_with_index(xls_offset) do |row, idx|
  pp expected_tooltip = row[1]
   expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(#{row_offset+idx}) .tvCell:nth-child(6) 
   img[tooltip='#{expected_tooltip}']")
end

Comment: it looks like it is validating the blank row of the worksheet

Comment: If I use this way                                                                                                        
xls_offset = 2
row_offset = 2  the error is:  Reason:, expected `#<Capybara::Session>.has_css?("tr.tvRow:nth-child(59) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='']")` to be truthy, got false,